# LINQ to XML and namespace prefixes

Tags: linq-to-xml

From PRO LINQ bool:

> With linq to xml, namespace prefixes
>   get expanded on the input and honored
>   on the output. On the inside, they no
>   longer exist

a) I assume by **expanded on input** quote refers to expanding prefixes to fully qualified names when loading XML file into `XDocument`?

b) Is in the above quote the term **output** used only to describe saving `XElement` or `XDocument` to a file or some other medium, or is in the above context `Console.Writeline(XDocument_Instance);` also considered an output?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(XDocument_Instance)` basically calls `ToString()` on the `XDocument` instance and that is certainly considered "output" respectively serialization of the object.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "respectively serialization of the object"? 2) Is my assumption under a) correct?

Comment: "serialization" is just a term I prefer in the context of generating markup from an in-memory tree like LINQ to XML or DOM or XPath/XSLT. As far as I understand it your assumption under a) is correct but it is always difficult to judge stuff like that based on a short quote, that's why I did not answer a) in my original reply.